# Incorrect Client ID

Tags: google-analytics

I have trouble. After adding a clientID custom dimension in my report started tracking such strange data https://prnt.sc/rtdlk7 . There are just a few users with such clientID but I couldn't understand why it happening.

Comment: Could you please provide further details on your code, that stores the ClientID? As currently written, it is hard to tell, how this data is getting corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem certainly depends on how you send that value to Analytics, I would look for the problem on the content of the value that returns your function, it is definitely not a Google Analytics problem.